# SimpleXMLElement won't save readable well-formatted file

Tags: php, xml

Here's the code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count(array_values($resources['titles'])); $i++){
                //var_dump($key);
                $ad = $xml->addChild('ad');
                $ad->addChild('title', htmlentities(htmlspecialchars(substr($resources['titles'][$i], 0, 70))));
                $ad->addChild('text', 'Текст текст');
                $ad->addChild('price', htmlentities($resources['prices'][$i]));
                //file_put_contents('test.txt',$resources['titles'][$i]."\n", FILE_APPEND);

            }

$xml->asXML($this->_xmlOutput);
```

It saves all the data okay, but xml file is not formatted well and cyrillic symbols (theres a lot of them) turned into &#x447 (what is that code?). Also file is saved as ansi, not utf-8. So the question is - how to properly create well formatted and readable (with cyrillic symbols) XML document?

Comment: `substr` will not work correctly for UTF-8 strings.

Comment: But whats wrong with cyrillic and formatting. I cant get it. Maybe is there a way to force convertion to utf-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found better solution using DOMDocument. Heres rewrited example of code inside the loop:

```
            $node_ad = $xml->CreateElement('ad');
            $node_ads->appendChild($node_ad); 

            //$node_ads->addChild('title', htmlentities(htmlspecialchars(substr($resources['titles'][$i], 0, 70))));
            $title = $xml->CreateElement('title', htmlentities(htmlspecialchars(substr($resources['titles'][$i], 0, 70))));
            $node_ad->appendChild($title);

            $text = $xml->CreateElement('text', 'Текст текст');
            $node_ad->appendChild($text);

            $images_node = $xml->CreateElement('images');
            $node_ad->appendChild($images_node);                 

            $images = $xml->CreateElement('image', $this->_mainUrl.'/uploads/'.$resources['images'][$i]);
            $images_node->appendChild($images);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix XML with appropriate encoding header and tags[1](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php#110485). 
First line in XML should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt chage a thing. Stuck up to DOMDocument.

Comment: To get normal output use without quoting:

`$xml = html_entity_decode($xml, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: That function expects string but we got xml object so it doesnt work either.